# Can't match two dataframe values

Tags: r

I am not sure why the dataframe values do not match with each other.
I have a df name fileUpload which looks like this (the cols are aligned correctly):

```
Destination City    Year    Adults
Amsterdam   2015    2
Amsterdam   2016    2
Amsterdam   2015    2
Amsterdam   2016    2
Amsterdam   2015    3
```

There is a space after each city name.

I have another dataframe that is not uploaded, like this:

```
cities <- read.csv(text = "
      City,Lat,Long,Pop
      Amsterdam ,4.8952,52.3702,779808
      Bali ,115.1889,-8.4095,4225000")
```

I need to merge the two dataframes, but I realized that the city values returns not matching (`NA`). I tried checking it using `fileUpload %in% cities` returns `false`

I tried removing the space after the city, also did not work. 
The `typeof(df$city)` for both is integer.

How can I make the cities name match together?

Comment: Check `str(fileUpload)`, I bet your Destination is a factor. If so use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when reading it in or just transform it now to strings with `as.character()`. Same for the `cities`.

Comment: Please add a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments you should convert your columns to strings from factors.

```
mergedCities <- merge(fileUpload, cities, by.x ="Destination City", by.y = "City", all = TRUE)
```

Set the `all` parameter to specify if you want to keep all cities or just the one form x or y or only the cities present in both.